# how do i convert hexadecimal (floating point number) to decimal number in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am Developing a application in Visual c++ 2010 Win Forms Application, I will receive the hexadecimal data (packets) and store it in the Rich Text Box. The hexadecimal data which received will represent Floating Point Numbers.  For Ex: the Floating number 11.62 will be received as 4139eb85 (which is string stored in RichTextBox). I wanted to convert the hexadecimal number to its original value and display it. I am struggling to convert (for ex) 4139EB85 to its Original value 11.62

Pl any help me out at the earliest.

Comment: Are you receiving a string of 8 hexadecimal characters, or a stream of four bytes?

Comment: I will be receiving the stream of 4 bytes only. But it is stored in Textbox as a String.

Comment: I have one more confusion, how Hexadecimal which represents signed integer can be converted into Signed integer. For Ex. FFF4 represents -12. How do i convert FFF4 into its original sign Value.

Comment: If you're recieving the raw bytes `{0x41,0x39,0xEB,0x85}`, don't convert them to a hex-encoded string and back. That's just stupid.

Comment: No, I am just receiving it as 41 39 EB 85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the string as `UInt32` and then use [`BitConverter::ToSingle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle.aspx) to convert the bytes to a float:

```
// Convert the hex string into a UInt32 (if necessary)
UInt32 bits = UInt32::Parse("4139EB85", System::Globalization::NumberStyles::HexNumber);
// Convert the bytes of the UInt32 to a Single/float
float f = BitConverter::ToSingle(BitConverter::GetBytes(bits), 0);
```

Comment: Dear Sir, Got the output as expected. Thank You Very Much.

Comment: I have one more confusion, how Hexadecimal which represents signed integer can be converted into Signed integer. For Ex. FFF4 represents -12. How do i convert FFF4 into its original sign Value. Pl help me out with this.

Comment: @Deepak It's the same principle, just with a different type: 
`Int32::Parse("FFFFFFF4", System::Globalization::NumberStyles::HexNumber);`  
"FFF4" are only two bytes though, so you either need to parse as `Int16`, or sign-extend the bytes (as I did, if First bit is set, pad left with 1s) before parsing. If you always receive just two bytes, i'd suggest you just parse it as `Int16`.

Comment: But am getting Value 0 instead of -12

Code is given below:

String ^hex="FFF4";
Int32 bits = Int32::Parse(hex, System::Globalization::NumberStyles::HexNumber);
int f = BitConverter::ToSingle(BitConverter::GetBytes(bits), 0);
this->rt1->Text = f.ToString();

Comment: @Deepak Yes *as i said*, you only have TWO bytes. So you will need to parse those as **`Int16`**: `Int16::Parse(/* etc. */)` This will work with your input.

Comment: I used Int16 instead of Int32 but getting an Exception "System.ArgumentException": Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.

Comment: @Bolt got signed value only!! I used BitConverter::ToInt16 instead of BitConverter::ToSingle Method.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Deepak Please look at the documentation of `Int16::Parse`. You *don't* need to call `BitConverter::ToInt16` when you only have an `Int16`. You already have the value you want after you called `Int16::Parse`. When you learn about new methods, it's always a good idea to have a look at their documentation, so you know what they actually do and so you can use them most effectively in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Not portable, but:

```
int x = 0x4139eb85;
float y = *reinterpret_cast<float *>(&x);
```